# pandas dataframe not exporting to csv correctly, missing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

In my code below I have a list of entries that go into a function.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

jam_list = []

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period='max')
    price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    price_df.drop(price_df.columns[[0,1,2,4,5,6]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    price_df['tic'] = (ticker)
    return price_df

l = ["AAPL", "KO"]
for ticker in l:
    jam = price(ticker)
    jam_list.append(jam)
    jam_df = pd.DataFrame(jam)
    print(jam_df)
    jam_df.to_csv('jam_df.csv')
```

When I print the DataFrame `jam_df` I get this,

```
             Close scoop
Date                    
1980-12-12    0.41  AAPL
1980-12-15    0.38  AAPL
...            ...   ...
2020-05-14  309.54  AAPL
2020-05-15  307.71  AAPL

[9940 rows x 2 columns]
            Close scoop
Date                   
1962-01-02   0.00    KO
1962-01-03   0.00    KO
...           ...   ...
2020-05-14  43.70    KO
2020-05-15  43.26    KO
[14695 rows x 2 columns]
```

When I export it to a csv file I will only get the KO part, the second part of the print version. How do I make the csv export both parts AAPL and KO?

Comment: By naming differently the csv file? You're looping and at each loop the previous file is replaced...

Comment: You have two different data frames.  The last one is overwriting your first one because you're looping twice over the same file name.  Perhaps you meant to save it as different files? `jam_df.to_csv('jam_df_{name}.csv'.format(name=ticker))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export after your loop, after having concatenated your df list

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

jam_list = []

def price(ticker):
    company = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    price = company.history(period='max')
    price_df = pd.DataFrame(price)
    price_df.drop(price_df.columns[[0,1,2,4,5,6]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    price_df['tic'] = (ticker)
    return price_df

l = ["AAPL", "KO"]
for ticker in l:
    jam = price(ticker)
    jam_list.append(jam)
    jam_df = pd.DataFrame(jam)#useless
    print(jam_df)
full_df = pd.concat(jam_list)
full_df.to_csv('jam_df.csv')
```

see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat

Comment: This can be simplified to `full_df = pd.concat([price(ticker) for ticket in ["AAPL", "KO"]])`.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the for loop ran twice, once for "APPL" and once for "KO". The output paths are the same('jam_df.csv'), so the output for APPL got overwritten.

Comment: can I make some type of for loop so they can both go into the csv file?

Comment: @Wli's answer does exactly that